# How to automatically enable tests to run in parallel within a package?

Tags: go, testing, parallel-processing

I would like to run tests in a package in parallel. We know that the [`testing.Parallel` function](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Parallel) enables us to run two tests in a package in parallel, but is there a way to automatically enable all tests in a package to run in parallel without calling `t.Parallel()`?

For example, are there any flags I can throw into `go test` to make all tests with the function signature `func(t *testing.T)` be ran in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from [commit f80d8fb](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/f80d8fbcf0851959c047d55d0b31bbeb256a9f0c) and Go1 (Oct. 2011)

An option (`--parallel`) was [debated at the time](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-dev/RAKiqi44GEU/discussion), but quickly rejected:

> Many tests won't work if run in parallel. (Many will, too.)
>   The presence of a `--parallel` flag means scripts and so on will want to turn it on, and tests must be able to protect themselves from erroneous runs.
>
> I suggest whitelisting individual tests that are knowingly able to run
>   in parallel, and the easiest way to do this is to name them
>   differently.
>
> I like `t.Parallel`.
>   It's clear which tests are parallel, it's not a global default, so you can apply it just to the tests where it is both appropriate and necessary,
>   and the behavior is great: all the non-parallel run
>   first - meaning the easy ones - and then the parallel
>   ones can chew cpu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess based on this, there is no built in way to make all tests in a package parallel?

Comment: @hlin117 Yes, no "global option" that would quickly make all test parallel... An explicit naming convention is still required.